# Java oversize List from array Arrays.asList vs. AbstractList performance issue

Tags: java, arrays, performance, junit

**The situation:**

A (huge) array of elements requires performant transformation into a List, extended by one value. To solve the problem, a reduced implementation of AbstractList was devised and used in a dedicated method, which performs very well.

**The Problem:**

Simply applying `Arrays.asList(String element, String[] elements)` will not work (which would be very fast). Trying any other, seemingly straight-forward approaches will fail, due to serious performance problems.

**Consider following examples, of which none will perform well:**

```
protected static <T> List<T> slowAsList(final T last, final T... elements) {

    //1
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(0, length)
      .mapToObj(i -> i < length ? elements[i] : last)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());

    //2
    return Stream.concat(Stream.of(first), Arrays.stream(elements))
      .parallel()
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
    //3
    return new ArrayList() {{ for (Object o : elements) add(o); add(last); }};

    //4
    final ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
    arrayList.add(last);
    for (Object o : elements) arrayList.add(o);
    return arrayList;

    //5
    final int arrayLen = elements.length + 1;
    final Object[] array = Arrays.copyOf(elements, arrayLen);
    for (int i = 1; i < arrayLen; i++) {
      array[i] = elements[i - 1];
    }
    array[arrayLen - 1] = last;
    return Arrays.asList(array);
}
```

The method will stall in a JUnit test and not finish in a feasible amount of time:

```
@Timeout(15)
@Test
public void fastAsListTest() {
    final Object[] testStrings1MwithNull = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 1000000)
      .mapToObj(i -> i == 1000000 ? null : "TEST" + i)
      .toArray();

    slowAsList(testStrings1MwithNull);
}
```

When replacing the implementation in the method with a variation of the `AbstractList` implementation, the test will finish within a few milliseconds, instead:

```
protected static <T> List<T> fastAsList(final T last, final T... elements) {
    if (elements == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return new AbstractList<T>() {
      @Override
      public int size() {
        return elements.length;
      }
      @Override
      public T get(int index) {
        return index < 0 ? null : elements[index];
      }
    };
}
```

**EDIT:**
This was the original code, with `first` as additional element

```
protected static List<Object> asList(final Object first, final Object[] elements) {
    
    return new AbstractList<Object>() {
      @Override
      public int size() {
        return elements.length + 1;
        // return elements != null ? elements.length + 1 : 0;
      }
    
      @Override
      public Object get(int index) {
        return (index == 0) ? first : elements[index - 1];
        // return (index == 0) ? first : elements!= null ? elements[index - 1] : null;
      }
    };
```

The commented-out code shows the added `null` checks, for nulls causing `com.sun.jdi.InvocationException` with elements `null`.

**EDIT2:**
Jet another attempt, this time trying to apply the fast code as inline `Collector` in a `Stream` approach (with same results):

```
final int length = elements.length;
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(0, length)
      .mapToObj(i -> i < length ? elements[i] : null)
      .collect(() -> new AbstractList<T>() {
        @Override
        public int size() {
          return elements == null ? null : elements.length;
        }
        @Override
        public T get(int index) {
          return index < 0 ? null : elements[index];
        }
        }, 
        (a,b) -> {return;}, 
        (a,b) -> {return;}
      );
```

What could be causing this issue, might a lack of memory be the problem here?

I've ramped-up Xms/Xmx to 2G/6G for the test and have an overall memory consumption of ~83% (of 16G in total) in Windows. Lowering the values hasn't changed anything, though.

**EDIT3:**

The only option that seems to provide comparable performance so far - working only, if no additional value is required - is a plain wrapped `Arrays.asList()`:

```
protected static <T> List<T> fastAsList(final T... elements) {
  return elements == null ? null : Arrays.asList(elements);
}
```

Comment: Warning!  When using.  return index < 0 ? null : elements[index];.   Does this actually return the correct results UPON THE ELEMENTS.  It seems awfully subtle it may be deceiving and  bypassing it's work. Have you checked by specially tainting the test elements and values for the exact result from throughput!!!!    NB:  You also may want the G1 garbage collector , see it's docs and the SDK docs for it.

Comment: Your `fastAsList` version is faster because it doesn't copy the array; it just wraps it. If your speed and memory constraints prohibit the "slow" options, the "fast" version makes sense (except that it ignores `last`, but that looks easy to fix).

Comment: Shouldn't the implementation of `size()` be `return elements.length + 1`? And when calling `get`, shouldn't it return `last` too?

Comment: Well, the original code was like this:
`return (index == 0) ? first : elements[index - 1]`
"last" was only a quick modification, for this, it should've probably been `return (index == elements.length - 1) ...`

And for `size()` it was `return elements.length + 1;` indeed. I was copying the code out of another method based on the original code without an additional element for this example, sorry.

Comment: @all: I've written a unit test which checks the first, last and expected additional value, as well as the expected length (and verified in the debugger), so the List actually contains all the array elements and first/last. It's also unmodifiable, since either `add`, `addAll` or `set` will throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

What better ways would there be to wrap the (extended) array, that are equally performing?

Comment: What is your requirement? If it's a readable List made of an array plus one value, without the overhead of copying the array, use such a custom subclass of `AbstractList`. If that is not suitable, what is it lacking?

Comment: Well, it's to create an immutable `List` from an `Array` with additional values, also allowing `null`, as fast as possible. `Arrays.asList()` perfectly fits the bill for cases, where no additional elements are required, but `null` values are, as far as I'm concerned - while `List.of()` doesn't support nulls and both don't allow for added elements. I was curious, why this specific approach is this fast - so far, I've got not conclusive answer to that question, 'wrapped' array isn't convincing - and if there'd be other, equally fast approaches, that are more elegant (as in 'more fluent') to use.

Comment: It's fast because in that version you **don't copy the array**. "More elegant" and "more fluent" are opinion-based and not suitable questions. If your "fast" solution does what you want, use that.

Comment: By 'wrapped array is not convincing' I mean: there must be some kind of copying/extending the source array by `AbstractList` or `AbstractCollection`, otherwise the additional element couldn't be added, without backtracing it to the core. And by 'more fluent' I mean being able to use it in a chained manner, like with the `Stream` API. Unfortunately, creating streams - and collecting them - seems to produce quite an overhead, which needs to be considered, if the invocation happens in a loop, where I found a dedicated `Collector` being even more demanding, than an inline Collector.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now, my bad. The method doesn't do any copying, it just returns the additional value, in case the value for index 0 is retrieved (first) or, in principle, at whatever index the addition is desired, else only the unmodified List-wrapped source array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is: The return object of AbstractList is a simple Reference instance. The field of return object is your huge array.

And in other words, there is not real copy.

Comment: If you mean by this, that the resulting `List<T>` would only contain one element with the source array, no. The list contains all the elements from that, plus the extended value, as desired.

Comment: I've chosen this as solution, altough a better understanding of the example above was inspired by other comments, too.

Comment: There is no need to guess something that is actually obvious. The only question is how someone could write that code in the first place, without understanding the its logic.

Comment: Sorry, to me it actually wasn't obvious in the first place, only at a second glance. The original (of course undocumented) code was 'invented' by somone else.

Comment: @fozzybear granted, the author should have documented that the list will keep referencing the array (and hence, reflect subsequent modifications). Compare with [the documentation of `Array.asList(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) which will also keep referencing the array (and even allow modifications to the array): “*Returns a fixed-size list* backed by the specified array. *Changes made to the array will be visible in the returned list, and changes made to the list will be visible in the array.*”

Comment: Yes, that's like what it should be, but the code docs are very bad, which I'm trying to improve a bit. I've already added a comment about the caveats.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly:

Your performance test is poor. Your JVM is not warmed-up, code needs to be JITed etc. It is even possible that the call to method under test can be compiled away - you don't use the result. Learn how to use JMH to get more insight on performance of each alternative.

Having said that:

All alternatives you arrived as are terribly slow as they copy elements of the source list into target list, one element at a time. You have't even set initial size of the output list - it starts with a small default value and needs to grow when you add elements. Again, more copying.

One alternative you haven't considered is:

- allocate target array with desired size
- use `System.arraycopy` to copy source array into desired position in the target array. `System.arraycopy` is the fastest method to copy arrays (equivalent to memcpy)

```java
static <T> List<T> slowAsList(final Class<T> clazz, final T firstElem, final T... sourceElements) {
    final int arrayLen = sourceElements.length + 1;
    final T[] targetArray = (T[])Array.newInstance(clazz, arrayLen);
    System.arraycopy(sourceElements,
            0,
            targetArray, 1, sourceElements.length);
    targetArray[0] = firstElem;
    return Arrays.asList(targetArray);
}

@Test
public void slowAsListTest() {
    final String[] testStrings1MwithNull = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 1000000)
            .mapToObj(i -> i == 1000000 ? null : "TEST" + i)
            .toArray(String[]::new);

    var ret = slowAsList(String.class, "1", testStrings1MwithNull);
    System.out.println(ret.size());
}
```

On my machine, this is faster than your wrapper implementation (again, not warmed up JVM)

On top of that: if your custom wrapper is a performance optimization and you won't wrap a wrapper of a wrapper..., then it seems a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: Thanks for your input on init size and JMH. Unfortunately, this example shows the same problem here. Besides, I've also used another approach based on `Arrays.copy()`, which should perform equally well as your example (similar as 'last' = null variation): `return Arrays.asList(Arrays.copyOf(elements, elements.length + 1));`, but this wouldn't work either. I'm unsure of the original author's goal, but I suppose it was to implement a fast `insert(0, value)` method. Either way, the performance boost seems dramatic compared to all available alternatives so far, which made me wonder about the why.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, on my machine the code I proposed is faster (same order of magnitude, though) than custom wrapper (for the input data as shown).

Comment: Then the question would be, why. What specs does your machine and environment (Xms/Xmx) have? Btw. I've also been using warmup code in my tests (looping the method invocation 1M), which I've stripped from the example for sake of readability.

Comment: @fozzybear did you ever verify that the method stalls at the trivial array copying operation and not at the creation of one million strings before that?

Comment: @Holger Yes, the generation of the test array just takes a few dozen or so milliseconds.

Comment: @fozzybear but this code not only creates one millions strings, it creates and populates an array with it. The last part alone is in the same order of magnitude as copying the array. There must be other reasons for the performance problem. Since I see a `@Test` annotation, I suspect you are running all these variants in a unit test which keeps references to them, so you’re running out of memory.